# Why WM_ERASEBKGND message is sent when I decrease a window size?

Tags: c, winapi

I have noticed that when I decrease a window size, a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message is being sent, can anyone explain why this message is being sent in this case, I mean I understand that when I increase a window size I should erase the background of the new shown area, but why do I need to erase the background when I decrease a window size?!

This is a screenshot that illustrates this behavior (I set Spy++ to only show `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages):

[image]

This is the code I used to create the window:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WinClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 400, 400, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention an important detail: when I decrease a window size, only a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message is sent **without the `WM_PAINT` message**.

Comment: It's not so much that you are expected to erase the background, more that you need, potentially, to repaint the entire contents.

Comment: You would normally use the CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW class styles and getting the message would not be surprise.  But you don't, then the painting gets subtly different.  Write your own message handler for WM_ERASEBKGND and call GetClipBox().  You'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the automatic erase sent on resize remove the CS_HREDRAW and/or CS_VREDRAW styles from the window class registration. Those flags tell the system to redraw the window on a horizontal or vertical resize respectively.

As for why this behavior could be desirable some controls keep text centered as they resize, if they did not erase the background artifacts from the old size might be left around.